# Split function inside Map isn't returning all values in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this code line:

```
'1,2,3,4-8,9,11,14-20'.split('-').map(value => value.split(',').map(Number));
```

For the example it must return three arrays like these:

```
[1,2,3,4] [8,9,11,14] [20]
```

and it does by using vanilla js, but, when I use it inside my angular project the returned arrays are like these:

```
[1,2,3] [9,11] []
```

as far as I test it, it seems to be related to the split inside a map function &
the weirdest part is that it returns the correct values if I print them in the browser console in the angular project:

```js
console.log(
  '1,2,3,4-8,9,11,14-19'.split('-').map(value => value.split(',').map(Number))
);
```

Comment: Mmm that should not happen .. Can you post the angular code when is giving the wrong result?

Comment: works like a charm: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sk38wx

Comment: Chrome browser console is a bit misleading in that it doesn't "log" values but "tracks" them. When you click the array open in chrome dev tools, it shows how the array currently is, not how it was when you did `console.log()`. Just something useful to keep in mind.